# $H^1(X;G) \cong \text{Hom}(\pi_1(X), G)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Hatcher exercise 3.1.5 contains the following: regarding a cochain $\phi \in C^1(X,G)$ as a function from paths in $X$ to $G$, show that if $\phi$ is a cocycle then (among other things) $\phi(f \cdot g) = \phi(f) + \phi(g)$ and $\phi(f) = \phi(g)$ is $f \simeq g$. Hatcher says that these two statements give a map $H^1(X,G) \to \text{Hom}(\pi_1(X), G)$, which the universal coefficient theorem says is an isomorphism if $X$ is path-connected. But I don't really understand why these two facts are needed to prove this statement; isn't the following enough?

Proof that $H^1(X;G) \cong \text{Hom}(\pi_1(X), G)$: By the universal coefficient theorem, $H^1(X;G)$  is naturally isomorphic to $\text{Hom}(H_1(X), G)$. If $X$ is path-connected, then $H_1(X)$ is naturally isomorphic to the abelianization of $\pi_1(X)$. By the universal property of abelianization, every map in  $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(X), G)$ factors uniquely through $H_1(X)$. This shows that $H^1(X;G)$ is naturally isomorphic to $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(X), G)$.

Is there something wrong with my proof? Do we need the facts stated in the first paragraph? I've found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860688/is-there-an-isomorphism-mathrmhomh-1x-g-simeq-mathrmhom-pi-1x-g-w) thread, but I'm still confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is nothing wrong with your proof. In Hatcher's exercise you just define explicitly the isomorphism $H^1(X, G) \to \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(X), G)$, instead of just knowing that it exists.